# Cross-Domain Cookie fix for Safari in February 2015?

Tags: cookies, safari, cross-domain

I have a website (A) with an iframe that loads a website (B) that is on a different domain. This website (B) uses cookies. Safari is blocking these cookies by default.

Since all the solutions out there to this problem seem to no longer work anymore, are there any new developments now in February 2015?

I'm very interested in a solution that doesn't require the end user to change a setting in their browser. Thank you.